# when exactly the combiner runs for each mapper output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

when exactly the combiner runs, though you mention the combiner class in your driver code, its still up to hadoop to decide whether it should run on each mapper output. Could you please explain on what basis( is there any thump rule or equation or formula) hadoop decides this combiner job execution.

Answer (score 0):

The combiner runs after the mapper and before the reducer. It runs for every mapper output. It can be seen as a part of the mapper, so the input of the reducer is actually the output of the combiners. Each mapper may consist of many map tasks, so that's maybe something that got you confused. It acts as a "mini-reducer", meaning that it groups all the values that have the same key (the output of mapper), but only for the data that has been output from the mapper, and not for all the data, unlike the reducer.

See this [Yahoo Tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my question is when exactly it runs? suppose say i have explicitly declared the combiner class in my Driver code, say my mapper output is less, will combiner run in this case?

Comment: What do you mean less? Less than what? The Combiner will run in any case, if you set a Combiner class in your driver code. If you have no map output, then it will not run.

Comment: I red in some forums saying that the combiner runs on no of spills... could anyone explain how this works?